# Problem with salesforce 1 App

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

While i am running my site on Salesforce1 App then it is showing this Error:

Error**-[You cannot view this page. either because you don't have permission salesforce or because the page is not supported on mobile devices salesforce]**
Help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using communities? If yes, and if you have an inline VF page or MDP action calls VF page, then this is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008X6hAAE) which will be addressed in Spring 15.

Comment: yes i am using communities..Yeah Got it ..!!